# Adding Column Names to Foreach Output in R

Tags: r, loops, foreach

**EDIT**

It took too long for me to get back to this, but I have finally developed a short example that sufficiently explains my problem.

```
foreach(i=1:4,.combine='rbind') %do% {
mymod <- lm(iris[,i] ~ Species, data=iris)
varname <- names(iris)[i]
versicolor.coef <- summary(mymod)$coef[2,1]
versicolor.pval <- summary(mymod)$coef[2,4]
virginica.coef <- summary(mymod)$coef[3,1]
virginica.pval <- summary(mymod)$coef[3,4]
finaldata <- c(varname, versicolor.coef, versicolor.pval, virginica.coef, virginica.pval)
}
```

*Output*

```
         [,1]           [,2]     [,3]                   [,4]    
result.1 "Sepal.Length" "0.93"   "8.77019424057073e-16" "1.582" 
result.2 "Sepal.Width"  "-0.658" "1.83248917685803e-17" "-0.454"
result.3 "Petal.Length" "2.798"  "5.25458742021435e-69" "4.09"  
result.4 "Petal.Width"  "1.08"   "1.25497770422215e-57" "1.78"  
         [,5]                  
result.1 "2.21482134895686e-32"
result.2 "4.53895687858888e-10"
result.3 "4.1061386190517e-91" 
result.4 "7.95174798237392e-86"
```

First, is there a way to get by without the `finaldata` argument at the end? Or otherwise better-define what I want printed in the final output file? If not, I just noticed that I can do something like `"varname"=varname` and the column will be called `varname`, so that is a potential work-around. Ideally though, I'd like it to use every value for output except `mymod`...

**INITIAL POST**

Here is a toy example of a far-more complicated `foreach` loop that I'm working with:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5,ncol=5)

loopdata <- foreach(i=1:ncol(data),.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
  meanval <- mean(data[,i])
  sdval <- sd(data[,i])
  result.data <- c(meanval,sdval)
}
```

Which has the following output:

```
> loopdata
                [,1]      [,2]
result.1  0.84504825 1.4647076
result.2 -0.40036228 0.6653162
result.3  1.16711233 0.7605012
result.4 -0.48205580 0.4448445
result.5 -0.07249848 0.7525871
```

I would like to have the column names marked with `meanval` and `sdval` as in the foreach loop. Right now, I'm doing this as follows:

```
loopdata <- data.frame(loopdata)
names(loopdata) <- c("meanval","sdval")

> loopdata
             meanval     sdval
result.1  0.19357026 0.8110218
result.2 -0.04431897 1.1634896
result.3  0.30790173 0.6394632
result.4  0.10934219 1.4110413
result.5 -0.73314671 0.3445583
```

One problem is that my actual code has some user-defined values that change the possible column names that can be generated every time, and the total number of columns varies, as well as the column names. Right now, I'm concatenating the results at the end of the foreach code with a `c()` function, and writing out different c() functions based on the potentially different set-ups from the user-defined code using if-else. After the full `loopdata` is generated, I assign the column names by re-typing out the potential options for column names.

My method is currently quite accident-prone and cumbersome. Is there a more-efficient way of doing it? I'd be willing to look into other options as well.

Comment: You need to show more of your *actual code*. Your large block of text needs to be illustrated with script lines (i.e., show don't tell). The below answers took on your simplistic need which seems not to work for actual needs.

Comment: Sorry! I was in a rush, so my example wasn't quite as fleshed out as it should have been. I will work to improve it this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of using a loop. We can try,

```
new_df <- data.frame(meanval = colMeans(data), sdval = apply(data, 2, sd))
new_df
#     meanval     sdval
#1  0.19357026 0.8110218
#2 -0.04431897 1.1634896
#3  0.30790173 0.6394632
#4  0.10934219 1.4110413
#5 -0.73314671 0.3445583
```

Or with `matrixStats` package we can directly get standard deviation column wise with `colSds` function

```
library(matrixStats)
new_df <- data.frame(meanval = colMeans(data), sdval = colSds(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by naming it in the `c()` step

```
library(foreach)
foreach(i= 1:ncol(data), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
              m1 <-  mean(data[,i])
              sd1 <- sd(data[,i])
              c(meanval= m1, sdval=sd1)
 }
#             meanval     sdval
#result.1  0.19357026 0.8110218
#result.2 -0.04431897 1.1634896
#result.3  0.30790173 0.6394632
#result.4  0.10934219 1.4110413
#result.5 -0.73314671 0.3445583
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data)[, .(meanval=unlist(lapply(.SD, mean)), sdval = unlist(lapply(.SD, sd)))]
#       meanval     sdval
#1:  0.19357026 0.8110218
#2: -0.04431897 1.1634896
#3:  0.30790173 0.6394632
#4:  0.10934219 1.4110413
#5: -0.73314671 0.3445583
```

Or as the output has the same type, we can get with a single `lapply` and then `transpose` it

```
setnames(as.data.table(data)[, transpose(lapply(.SD, 
       function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))))], c('meanval', 'sdval'))[]
#       meanval     sdval
#1:  0.19357026 0.8110218
#2: -0.04431897 1.1634896
#3:  0.30790173 0.6394632
#4:  0.10934219 1.4110413
#5: -0.73314671 0.3445583
```

Comment: I think I like your first option best. The issue is that I'm not doing simple means and standard deviations for each column, but rather running three different statistical models, selecting one based on the best AIC, and printing out coefficients, p-values, and additional related information for each column (such as the number of zeros, etc).

Comment: @Katie Yes, you can still do this with the `data.table` and other option..  But without more info, I don't know how you are doing it.  Also, this is based on the example you showed

Comment: Yes, I see my issue! I will work on an example this evening that more-clearly defines the subtleties of the issue I'm trying to fix. Thank you so much for your help!